# Ubuntu desktop only loads GTK theme after second login

Tags: unity, gtk

I have Ubuntu 14.04 with default Unity

The first time I log into ubuntu, it seems GTK is having some problems, the buttons appear very squared, the font is wrong, non anti-aliased and the windows theme seems to fallback to some default. I have to Logout from my current session, log back in to make everything come back to normal.

What can cause this and how can I fix it?

Comment: I seem to have a [similar (or the same?) problem](http://askubuntu.com/q/834785/161463). Did you find a cause/solution in your case?

Comment: @bluenote10 That was almost two years ago but I remember that I made a full update with apt-get update and apt-get dist-upgrade. I remember doing a dpkg --reconfigure as well but I don't remember if it had any effect. If all else fails you could install Cinnamon, it's another graphic environment that I've found better than Unity and less prone to misconfigurations in my opinion. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

your GTK must be messed up because your GTK theme shouldnt be messed up because when i log in to ubuntu i can see my GTK theme clearly with square shapes or anything the only worst case scenario  would be that a hacker logged into your cpu and this is just guessing im guessing that he uploaded an invisible software and thats what made your GTK all messed up. im sorry to hear this :< if your computer changes let me know