# GTK theme / font rendering broken on first login, but works on second login

Tags: 14.04, fonts, gtk

For a few months I'm experience strange font rendering issue on an Ubuntu 14.04 system. When I login for the first time after the system is booted, something is wrong with the font rendering. Examples:

[image]

[image]

All GTK dialogs do not seem to use the Ubuntu font any more, the font size is wrong and hinting seems to be broken.

If I log out and log back in, everything looks nice and exactly as it used to be:

[image]

[image]

I'm using the default Ambience theme, with the default Ubuntu font -- the only thing I have changed is to slightly decrease the default font size using `unity-tweak-tool`. I have verified that the font settings does not change in `unity-tweak-tool` when the font looks wrong: The setting for "Default font" is always "Ubuntu 8", but is apparently not applied in the first login.

Any ideas what could be causing this issue? How can I find out what changes during the log-out/log-in procedure in terms of GTK state?